# jquery not working in internet explorer but does with other browsers, "Object doesn't support this property or method "

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, internet-explorer

I've already tried [the jquery forum](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/this-line-fails-in-internet-explorer-but-not-firefox-or-chrome) for answers but didn't get any.

The page loads fine in chrome and firefox, but not IE, where it chokes
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method 
jquery-1.7.2.js, line 5276 character 6

The call stack is

```
dirNodeCheck

Sizzle
Sizzle
PSEUDO
filter
Sizzle
Sizzle
find
processXML
```

and the line of code of mine it fails on is

```
$(xmldoc).find("idea:not(idea idea)").each( function(index) {
```

It seems to fail in the find method where it fails an sizzle.isXML check, but I don't know if that's the real reason for it failing.

I've tried all jquery versions down to 1.1 and that did not improve anything.  I've also tried switching internet explorer 9 to various compatibility modes without improvement.

In all browsers, internet explorer and the ones that render correctly, the code below prints the same output to the console (isXMLDoc is false, length shows that all the elements are there).

```
_("isxml: " + $.isXMLDoc(xmldoc));
_("len: "+ xmldoc.find("idea").length);
```

Internet explorer was also the only browser that insisted I start up a web server and load from 127.0.0.1 rather than file:///, where I wonder if it is related to this problem.  I've wondered if the mime types are incorrect (internet explorer tries to download some remote web pages as files instead of opening them) but I don't know how to  correct it if that's the case.  The mime settings shown in the IIS manager show that .xml files are mapped to text/xml.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with yout ":not", is it not supposed to be ".idea"? Also why do you have "idea idea" in there?

Comment: This selector gives me the 'top level' ideas, i.e. ideas that are not nested within other ideas.  And it works just fine in the other browsers.